# Laptop freezes before/during post

Tags: laptop, boot, bios, freeze, post

I have an [Asus K70AB](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/K70AB/) which has had an issue for a while. When it boots, there's a chance it'll **freeze** for an **indefinite time** before it seems to start doing anything. What it will do is:

- The lights turn on, the fans start rotating and the CD drive makes a ticking sound for a second
- It'll have a **black screen** for an indefinite time. This may not happen at all, or may take even **up to 15 minutes** or so
- The POST screen comes up and everything seems to work normally, after which it'll continue to boot into Windows

This all leads me to think that there's a hardware related issue. I have tried to do the following things; all without any results, in the following order:

- I have taken out the HDD
- I have reset the BIOS to its factory settings
- I have flashed the BIOS to its newest version
- I have replaced the CMOS battery
- I have taken out the CD drive
- I have taken out both RAM sticks (one at a time)

At this point, I'm clueless as to what could be causing my issues. I was hoping someone here might have a suggestion which I forgot about.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I know that is hard to check and harder to happen in notebooks, but try to check for bulged capacitors in the motherboard. Something like [capacitor plague](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Al-Elko-bad-caps-Wiki-07-02-17.jpg).

[image: bad capacitor]
[image: another bad capacitor]

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a SD-Card without card or defective card attached to the SD-Card reader slot. The reader checks for bootable devices and can delay a system startup. 
Some guys booted their machines without hdd, went into the BIOS, loaded defaults and booted the machine with hdd again. I am not sure if that will work for you, but it's probably worth a try.